# How do I set the opacity of an undecorated JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

I've been having trouble setting the opacity of a window that I would like to be able to fade in gradually. For now, I'm going to stick with just setting it mostly transparent and keeping it that way. I've been having trouble doing even that. The following code should remove the window decorations and make it mostly transparent. While the decorations are removed, the window still stays completely opaque.

```
Color transparent = new Color(((float) 1.0), ((float) 1.0), ((float) 1.0), ((float) 0.25));
colorPickerWindow.setUndecorated(true);
colorPickerWindow.setBackground(transparent);
```

Thanks in advance for you help!

Edit:

```
 colorPickerWindow.setOpacity(0.5f);
```

gives me

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: TRANSLUCENT translucency is not supported.
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1):

```
colorPickerWindow.setOpacity(0.5f);
```

Note: setOpacity expects a float.

Comment: Won't even start now. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: TRANSLUCENT translucency is not supported.

Comment: @user119567 colorPickerWindow is of type JFrame, right? Make sure you're setting the opacity after your call to `setUndecorated()`.
The following works fine for me:

`JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        
        frame.setOpacity(0.5f);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: I did exactly what you did, and it is still saying that translucency is not supported.

Comment: I seem to be able to reproduce your problem. Could you try setting the application's look-and-feel to Nimbus? Just taking a shot in the dark here... If that doesn't work, I'm afraid your platform may not support these operations (as aries23 suggested). The code I posted works as expected on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all platforms supports setOpacity (according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).

Perhaps this can help? http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html